# Is there Anypoint Studio for Mule that is Community Edition?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I believe that *Mule Studio* became **Anypoint Studio**. Is there a version of Anypoint Studio that is open source (free)? Specifically, I'm referring to the GUI workflow designer tool.

Comment: Anypoint Studio is no longer free, it's 30 days trial. To me this sound as MuleSoft hit its ceiling and now trying to squeeze money from everything that is possible.

Comment: Anypoint Studio 7 is free to download, but no longer seems to work with Community Edition runtimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an answer to my question (thanks @Ryan), but it comes with a caveat. Yes, Anypoint Studio is open source but, by default, comes with the Enterprise runtime. One can download the Community Edition (CE) and use Anypoint Studio with that.

The caveat, however, is after taking time to configure a flow with the included DataMapper component, I received the following error when attempting to run my flow with the community edition. Basically, to execute a flow with DataMapper, you'll need the Enterprise version. *DataMapper does not execute with the CE*.

[image: DataMapper-With-CE-no-go]

Comment: ...which is not all that bad, considering the DataMapper is being deprecated in favour of their "Transform Message" component (aka. "dataweave"). I'm on an Enterprise system and have had "too much" grief trying to install the DataMapper on the test server (it's _available_ but not installed out of the box), so we went the "weave" route.

Answer (score 5):

Anypoint Studio is just one offering for both Community and Enterprise editions. It is free to download and you just need to make sure you use the community runtimes using the following Update Site here: 
Mule ESB Runtimes for Anypoint Studio - http://studio.mulesoft.org/r3/studio-runtimes

This runtime will then be available when you create a new project via the wizard or you can change an existing project by editing the mule-project.xml config file.

More details here: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime

Comment: Thanks for the info, Ryan. I just installed Anypoint Studio v5.2.1. When I went to install the Community Edition (CE) runtime, the latest was v3.6.0. I then changed the install site to [http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes](http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes) (notice the "**r4**") and was able to install runtime v3.7.0 CE. Is this the recommended/latest compatible runtime for this Anypoint Studio version?

Comment: Hi Ryan, this links http://studio.mulesoft.org/r3/studio-runtimes does not works. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the new process is to get the trial of AnyPoint Studio and then download the Community Edition via Help / Install New Software / Mule Runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Mule Studio changed to Anypoint Studio which is open source and comes with the Enterprise Edition.
Community Edition is also available for download.

Few of the things like Datamapper which is deprecated and replaced with Data weave won't run on Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Community version can be downloaded from MuleSoft website. Community edition comes with only open source connectors. For enterprise level connectors, you would need to have valid licensed version.